# How do I get properties out of NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, touchjson

I have a webservice that returns data to my client application in JSON. I am using [TouchJson](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) to then deserialize this data into a NSDictionary. Great. The dictionary contains a key, "results" and results contains an NSArray of objects.

These objects look like this when printed to log i.e

```
NSLog(@"Results Contents: %@",[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0 ]);
```

Outputs:

```
Results Contents: {
    creationdate = "2011-06-29 22:03:24";        
    id = 1;
    notes = "This is a test item";
    title = "Test Item";
    "users_id" = 1;
}
```

I can't determine what type this object is. How do I get the properties and values from this object?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a `NSDictionary` you're seeing there in `Results`.  You can tell by seeing the object & key pairs. For example, "users_id" is the key, and `1` is the object.

Comment: It's an NSDictionary. Use `-objectForKey:` to get each one. E.g. `NSString * title = [[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"title"];`

Comment: i'm betting they're all NSStrings, but the 1's may be NSNumbers - when printing a dictionary, the quotes are put around a string if there's a space in it, and not if there's not (thus you can't tell that the 1's are/aren't a string

Comment: The first is more likely an NSDate. Keep in mind that `%@` calls `-description` on an object, and the description is an `NSString`.

Comment: Thanks so much y'all. I didn't realize I was looking at a representation of an nsdictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the content of a `NSDictionary` you have to supply the key for the value that you want to retrieve. I.e:

```
NSString *notes = [[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"notes"];
```

Answer (score 2):

To test if object is an instance of class `a`, use one of these:

```
[yourObject isKindOfClass:[a class]]

[yourObject isMemberOfClass:[a class]]
```

To get object's class name you can use one of these:

```
const char* className = class_getName([yourObject class]);

NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([yourObject class]);
```

For an `NSDictionary`, you can use `-allKeys` to return an `NSArray` of dictionary keys. This will also let you know how many there are (by taking the `count` of the array). Once you know the type, you can call

```
[[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:keyString];
```

where `keyString` is one of `@"creationdate"`, `@"notes"`, etc. However, if the class is not a subclass of `NSObject`, then instead use:

```
[[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:keyString];
```

for example, you probably need to do this for `keystring` equal to `@"id"`.

Comment: to keep it Objective-C-ish `NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([yourObject class]);`